# No "USB Dialog Connection" option when enabling Developer Mode

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to enable Developer Mode on my Meta Quest 3 and am running into a problem while following 2 different official developer docs:

- [Setup Development Environment & Headset doc](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-env-device-setup/); and
- [Enable Developer Mode](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/native/android/mobile-device-setup/?locale=en_GB#enable-developer-mode) doc

I can confirm that I have logged in `dashboard.meta.com` using my normal Facebook account, I've created an "Org" and verified my credit card. I've enabled developer mode from inside the **Headset Settings** on the *Meta Quest* app on my phone.

Both documents now want me to do the exact same thing: put on my headset, and then go to **Settings >> System >> Developer**. And from there, they want me to turn on the **USB Dialog Connection** option.

The problem is, when I go to **Settings >> System >> Developer**, I only see these options:

[image]

As you can see, no mention of a "**USB Dialog Connection**" option. There is only a "**USB Link Auto-Connect**" option, but that's already enabled. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry? Am I in the wrong screen perhaps?

Also, secondary to that, can anyone clue me in here and explain what this "Quest PC app" is (from my screenshort) with respect to Meta Quest 3 development, and what it might be used for? Is it a debugger/emulator perhaps? I Googled it and it looks like it was something used for Oculus, so I'm not sure why the Meta Quest 3 has options available for it.

Comment: Is the second option working for you? Alternatively, you can open the Meta Quest Mobile App, select the headset from the list, and then turn on the Developer Mode option. Step 1 in the list said: `sign into the developer account`. Is your occulus account a dev account? For a normal phone there is usually a developer mode as well, depending on the model it involves clicking the build number a few times or similar actions

Comment: If you are developing on WIndows, do you have Android Device Bridge (ADB) configured/ installed? The option might not turn up before (that info is written at the top of your second link)

Comment: I know _nothing_ about Meta Quest 3 development @Zibelas, but I have both a Mac and a Windows machine. I currently have Unity fully installed on my Mac and would prefer to develop there. But if I have to code on Windows I can get everything installed on the family Windows machine, I just don't know what I'm supposed to do! Is Mac development an option? If so, what does the setup look like? And if not, what does the Windows setup look like?

Answer (score 0):

The quest pc app is used to manage your quest on your pc. It contains a store for VR games that (I believe) are meant to run on your computer. Furthermore, it acts as a bridge between your quest and the pc, and it needs to be running to make your quest talk via USB or airlink. I don't think I have needed usb communication since airlink. I am using a quest 1, so it may be different, but with airlink connected, your unity VR project (and any other game or app that can connect to the quest), should connect automatically. Try setting up airlink and see if it connects. If it does, you should be good to go for development.